# Malware detected on laravel phpunit

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, malware

i show message on my hosting cpanel: > Malware detected

my website build using laravel and the path that have Malware like hosting 
detected is

> vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/raimu.php

my phpunit version

> "phpunit/phpunit": "^7.0".

Is there any risk from this Malware?

Comment: is there a question about this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. There is not enough information for us to help with this. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: the question is who i can solve this problem or is there any risk from this Malware ?

Comment: at least the file is not present in the official repo https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/tree/7.0.0/src/Util/PHP - maybe try to use a newer version and update the dependency?

Comment: You shouldn't deploy dev dependencies to production.

Comment: @Namoshek who can I fix this problem?

Comment: @FerasMohamed it's possible that someone has gained access to your site and uploaded malicious scripts to various parts of your codebase. If that's the case, the file you're referencing is probably partially obfuscated to try and hide what it's doing. To fix, change your hosting passwords, clear your project code and re-install it from scratch to get rid of anything that shouldn't be there.